# Usando Netbeans para acessar BD PosgreSQL - jdbc.Drivers

Tags: java, postgresql, netbeans

Fiz a conexão no banco de dados usando o netbeans mas não está encontrando o DRIVE, aparentemente está tudo correto, mas retorna sempre o erro:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql:localhost:5432/Postgre

```
public class ConexaoBD {

public Statement stn; //pesquisa no banco de dados
public ResultSet rs; // armazena o resultado da pesquisa
private String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"; //identifica o nosso serviço BD
private String caminho = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Postgre"; //Qual o caminho do BD
private String usuario = "postgres";
private String senha = "xxxxxxx";
public Connection con; 

public void conexao(){
    
    try {
        System.setProperty("jdbc.Drivers", driver);
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(caminho, usuario, senha);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexão efetuada com sucesso");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro na conexão efetuada!\n"+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```